# Simulators do not appear in Visual Studio with Xcode 14, can anyone assist?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ios-simulator, xcode14

I have installed Xcode 14 in macbook. However, simulators do not appear in Visual Studio.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed in Visual Studio 17.3.5:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#1735--visual-studio-2022-version-1735

The latest version adds XCode 14 support.

Comment: This leads to an .exe download that opens Xamarin Profiler on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.
Solution - Updated Visual studio to 2022.
Thanks all of u for suggestions.

Comment: It's worth noting that the "Check for Updates…" feature in Visual Studio is broken, so that if you run it in a version Visual Studio with a previous "year" in the name, it won't list any newer editions (e.g. the 2019 version doesn't prompt you to update to 2022).

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 14 isn't supported by Xamarin. You will need to downgrade to Xcode 13 in order to get simulators working again.

In my case I even had to setup a new iPhone simulator from Xcode after downgrading.

You can find a link to XC13 [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/).

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended that you do not upgrade to Xcode 14 just yet and keep using Xcode 13.4.1. You could try to downgrade Xcode (Go to [downloads page](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin.html?path=%2Fdownload%2Fall%2F&appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&rv=0) in the Apple Developer Portal, sign in with your apple developer account, select Xcode13.4.1 to download and install). Then you can open Xcode, go to **Preferences** > **Location** > **Command Line Tools**, and make sure to select version 13.4.1.
You can also use the build from xcode14 branch if you need to keep Xcode 14. To get Xcode 14 support for Xamarin SDKs, follow [the guidance on GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15954). These SDKs will also come to Visual Studio.